# Why do I get an Could not deduce (Ord a) error?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to find the  list with the smallest sum of elements.:

```
shortest :: (Num a) => [[a]] -> [a]
shortest [] = []
shortest (x:xs) = if sum x < sum (shortest xs) then x else shortest xs
```

That gives me the following error:

> ```
> Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of `<'
> from the context (Eq a)
>   bound by the type signature for shortest :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
>   at code.hs:(8,1)-(9,71)
> Possible fix:
>   add (Ord a) to the context of
>     the type signature for shortest :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
> In the expression: sum x < sum (shortest xs)
> In the expression:
>   if sum x < sum (shortest xs) then x else shortest xs
> In an equation for `shortest':
>     shortest (x : xs)
>       = if sum x < sum (shortest xs) then x else shortest xs
> ```

Why doesn't the function typecheck?

Comment: `shortest` isn't really the right name for this, is it? — Consider using `minimumBy (compare \`on\` sum)`, with higher-order functions from `Data.List` and `Data.Function`.

Comment: To understand this problem, it's important to know that not all numbers can be ordered. Consider, for example, complex numbers like `1+2i`; there is no canonical way of ordering them.

Comment: @leftaroundabout already suggested a solution using library functions; but if you still want to write it from scratch as an exercise, besides fixing the type signature problem you need to consider what should be the value of `shortest []` or, in other words, what should be the basis of the recursion (hint: `minimum` and `maximum` are usually not defined for empty lists).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two type classes involved in this code: `Num` and `Ord`. Note
that a type can be a member `Num` and not `Ord`, and vice versa.

The type of `sum` is `Num a => [a] -> a` so the input elements to `shortest` needs to be a member of `Num`. You also do the following
in your code:

```
sum x < sum (shortest xs)
```

This means that you are using the operator `<` on `a`s, but in your type signature you have not required that the `a`s be an instance of `Ord` which defines `<`:

```
class Eq a => Ord a where
  compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
  (<) :: a -> a -> Bool
  ...
```

Therefore you need to add that requirement to your type signature:

```
shortest :: (Ord a, Num a) => [[a]] -> [a]
```

Or you could leave out the type signature.

Comment: One way to diagnose this type of problem, and to learn more about types and typeclasses at the same time, is to temporarily remove the type signature, load the module into GHCi, and then enter ":t shortest" to see what type the compiler assigned to it. Similarly, if you've left out the type signature, try adding it to see if your function has the type signature you expect. I've learned a lot using this technique.

Answer (score 6):

`Num` does not include `Ord`, so you're missing the `Ord` constraint on `a` in the type signature.  It should be

```
shortest :: (Num a, Ord a) => [[a]] -> [a]
```

You can remove the type signature and GHC will infer this for you.