# Graph search algorithm fails

Tags: haskell

I tried to modify my code that uses `Graph a` to find any vertices that are connected to vertex `n`. The definition of connection here is that vertex `m` is either directly connected to vertex `n` (via an edge) or connected to vertex `k` which in turn is connected to vertex `n`.

#### The code that I want to modify

```
-- ** Code 1 **

findPath :: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> [a]
findPath (Graph v w) a
    | [x | x<-v, x==a] == [] = []
    | otherwise = findPath' (Graph v w) [a]

findPath' :: Eq a => Graph a -> [a] -> [a]
findPath' (Graph [] _) _ = []
findPath' (Graph _ _) [] = []
findPath' (Graph v w) (tp:st)
    | [x | x<-v, x==tp] == [] = findPath' (Graph vv w) st
    | otherwise = tp : findPath' (Graph vv w) (adjacent ++ st)
    where
        adjacent = [x | (x,y)<-w, y==tp] ++ [x | (y,x)<-w, y==tp]
        vv = [x | x<-v, x/=tp]

connected :: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> a -> Bool
connected g a b =  if (a `elem` (findPath g b)) == True then True else False
```

#### My attempt at modifying it

```
-- **Code 2**

convert :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
convert [] = []
convert (k:v:t) = (k, v) : convert t


-- a is vertex
-- [a] is a list from neighbors
getEdges :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
getEdges _ [] = []
getEdges a (y:ys) = a : y : getEdges a ys


-- vertices :: Eq a => Graph a -> [a]
-- neighbors :: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> [a]
-- [a] is a list of vertex
mergeEdges :: Eq a => Graph a -> [a] -> [a]
mergeEdges _ [] = []
mergeEdges g (x:xs) = getEdges x (neighbors g x) ++ mergeEdges g xs

removeElements :: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
removeElements [] = []
removeElements ((a,b) : (v,w) : xs) =  [(a,b)] ++ removeElements xs

--v = vertex, w = edges
findPath :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,a)] -> a -> [a]
findPath v w a
    | [x | x<-v, x==a] == [] = []
    | otherwise = findPath' v w [a]

--v = vertex, w = edges
findPath' :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,a)] -> [a] -> [a]
findPath' [] _ _ = []
findPath' _ _ [] = []
findPath' v w (tp:st)
    | [x | x<-v, x==tp] == [] = findPath' vv w st
    | otherwise = tp : findPath' vv w (adjacent ++ st)
    where
        adjacent = [x | (x, y)<-w, y==tp] ++ [x | (y,x)<-w, y==tp]
        vv = [x | x<-v, x/=tp]

getParam :: Eq a => Graph a -> [(a,a)]
getParam g = removeElements ((convert(mergeEdges g (vertices g))))


connected :: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> a -> Bool
connected g a b = if (a `elem` (findPath (vertices g) (getParam g) b ) ) == True then True else False
```

#### Testing the code

This is my graph:  `Graph {vers = [-6,-3,5,3], edgs = [(-6,5),(3,-3),(-3,5)]}`

Code 1:

```
ghci> connected g 3 5
True
```

Code 2:

```
ghci> connected g 3 5
False
```

My best guess is that when I changed the argument from Graph a to a list of tuples [(a,a)] my code stoped working here but I don't understand why:

```
| otherwise = tp : findPath' vv w (adjacent ++ st)
where
    adjacent = [x | (x, y)<-w, y==tp] ++ [x | (y,x)<-w, y==tp]
```

I cannot use constructors from Graph a, (..), as it is not allowed :-( and therefore I need to modify my code.

#### Adding additional code

```
data Graph a = Graph {
  vers :: [Vertex a],
  edgs    :: [Edge a]
} deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

neighbors :: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> [a]
neighbors (Graph x []) _ = []
neighbors (Graph x ((v, w) : xs)) a
     | a == v = w : neighbors (Graph x xs) a
     | a == w = v : neighbors (Graph x xs) a
     | (v, w) : xs == [] = []
     | otherwise = neighbors (Graph x xs) a
```

Comment: What is `removeElements` supposed to do?

Comment: neighbors - returns the corresponding vertex from all edges that vertex n is a part of.  getEdges - helper function to mergeEdges, makes a list from vertex n and result from neighbors.  
mergeEdges - concat all edges from getEdges.    removeElements - all edges comes in duplicates, removeElemets eliminates every second edge from my list.   convert - convert my list to a list of tuples.

Comment: Is there a better way to use my findPath function? I have two functions  called     vertices :: Graph a -> [a] that will return a list of all vertices and a function called     neighbors:: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> [a] that returns a list of vertex which are neighbors of vertex n

Comment: Are you sure that the duplicate edges are next to each other in the list? From just reading the code, it seems to me that that can only happen if the `neighbors` function returns every neighbor twice, and I don't think that is the case. Can you check that the result of `getParam` is what you would expect?

Comment: Thank you for your comments and that you take your time to help me with this question :-) The reason why they are duplicates is that when I re-create the list from mergeEdges it sends all vertices to neighbors to get the pair-vertex. so If I have vertices [1,2,3,4] with edges [(1,2), (3,4)] neighbors will give me vertex = 1 => 2 and vertex = 2 =>1. mergeEdges will then create (1,2) and (2,1), whereas (2,1) is a "duplicate".

Comment: from testing Code 2 I've concluded that without Graph a, findPath does not identify vertices and edges that are not directly a neighbor. For example, [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)] findPath does not return 4 as being connected to 1 (which it is).

Comment: Can you give the implementation of `Graph` and the `neighbors` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run you `getParam` function on your example input `Graph {vers = [-6,-3,5,3], edgs = [(-6,5),(3,-3),(-3,5)]}` I get:

```
ghci> getParam g
[(-6,5),(-3,5),(5,-3)]
```

Here you can see that the edge (-3,5) and (5,-3) is duplicated and the edge (3,-3) has disappeared. So, I think your `removeElements` function is too simple. You could perhaps try a function that first sorts the tuple and then removes duplicates:

```
import Data.List (nub)

...

sortTuple :: Ord a => (a, a) -> (a, a)
sortTuple (x, y)
  | x <= y = (x, y)
  | otherwise = (y, x)

removeElements :: Ord a => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
removeElements xs = nub (map sortTuple xs)

-- also change the types of some other functions:
getParam :: Ord a => Graph a -> [(a,a)]
connected :: Ord a => Graph a -> a -> a -> Bool
```

Using that function I do get `getParam g == [(-6,5),(-3,3),(-3,5)]` and  `connected g 3 5 == True`.

But I'm also left wondering why you don't just use `getParams g = edgs g`?

Comment: thank you so much!! I'm gonna test that right away

Comment: this was acctually my thought for creating edgs, getParams g = edgs g. However as I'm not allowed to make module Graph(..) I cannot use it :-(

Comment: thank you so much, I got an error  "Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of `removeElements'" so my solution was to simply scrap removeElements. However I would love to test your code to see the results, do you know what I should do to fix that? I tried to follow this solution but it did not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003150/why-do-i-get-an-could-not-deduce-ord-a-error

Comment: Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of `removeElements'
      from the context: Eq a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   getParam :: forall a. Eq a => Graph a -> [(a, a)]
        at Assignment4.hs:149:1-38
      Possible fix:
        add (Ord a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            getParam :: forall a. Eq a => Graph a -> [(a, a)]
    * In the expression:
        removeElements ((convert (mergeEdges g (vertices g))))
      In an equation for `getParam':
          getParam g = removeElements ((convert (mergeEdges g (vertices

Comment: Yeah, sorry. You also need to replace all the `Eq a =>` constraints with `Ord a =>` on all the functions that have it, like `getParam`, and `connected`.